# Fill table row when there is nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table, where the  are filled if the user is present.

The JSON to check if he is present :

```
{"prenom":"Guillaume","nom":"HUART","date":"01-01-2019","heure":"06:00:00","dispo":"1","id":"1"},{"prenom":"Guillaume","nom":"HUART","date":"01-01-2019","heure":"07:00:00","dispo":"1","id":"1"},{"prenom":"Guillaume","nom":"HUART","date":"01-01-2019","heure":"08:00:00","dispo":"1","id":"1"},{"prenom":"Guillaume","nom":"HUART","date":"01-01-2019","heure":"09:00:00","dispo":"1","id":"1"},{"prenom":"Guillaume","nom":"HUART","date":"01-01-2019","heure":"10:00:00","dispo":"1","id":"1"}
```

So he appears in the table if dispo is 1.

Here is a pic of how it looks

### [image]

And this is how I want it to look :

[image]

I want to have a single line per username, and if the user is not available, instead of nothing, a black div.

I have tried in PHP but I can't get the result I want.

So I tried in javascript but the same..

---

Is javascript a good langage to do what I want ? Or I should try in PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: This is an opinion-based question (so far). It's also unclear.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no value, add `&nbsp;`. This will fill the table row (empty columns) with empty space.